# Invalid Escape Sequence cannot figure out the use of the escape character

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

This syntax:

```
executeJSCommand("location.href='StatusDetails.php?CHLD=1\&JNum=1024&JTitle=';");
```

Gives error:

> Invalid Escape Sequence

Answer (score -1):

```
executeJSCommand("location.href='StatusDetails.php?CHLD=1\\&JNum=1024&JTitle=';");
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answers. Please explain what you changed and why.

Comment: So I was trying to figure out the use of escape character to be used and I finally figured it out and posted the correct string with escape character in it as the answer.

Comment: Understood but you can at least leave a short comment on what you learned and what you changed for future people that see this answer. Please mark the answer as accepted also.